# The fact using htmlAttributes causes URL troubles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an asp .net project. I need to globalize it so I followed a tutorial (I'm a junior dev) on developpez.com ([This one](http://rdonfack.developpez.com/tutoriels/dotnet/internationalisation-application-asp-net-mvc-3-razor/)). I got a problem with the tutorial but after some searchs I resolve it. Currently, I got 2 links :

[image: links]

What I would like to do is to have flags instead of text. So, I want to add a class to the '< a >' element and put a background image. But when I add the class, the link generated by the Html.Helper is becoming strange. Some parameters are added, I don't understand why.

EDIT : I forgot to write that links doesn't change language when I add the class.

URLs before I add class to a link

```
<a href="/en">English</a>
<a href="/">[Français]</a>
```

URLs after I add class to a link

```
<a href="/?Count=6&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D">English</a>
<a class="drapeauFrance" href="/?Count=6&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D">[Français]</a>
```

How I include links to my partial view

```
@using MIFA.Helpers
@Html.LanguageSelectorLink("en", "[English]", "English", null)
@Html.LanguageSelectorLink("fr", "[Français]", "Français", new { @class = "drapeauFrance" })
```

How the LangageSelectorLink works

```
public static MvcHtmlString LanguageSelectorLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string cultureName, string selectedText, string unselectedText, object htmlAttributes, string languageRouteName = "lang", bool strictSelected = false)
{
    var language = helper.LanguageUrl(cultureName, languageRouteName, strictSelected);
    var link = helper.RouteLink(language.IsSelected ? selectedText : unselectedText, "LocalizedDefault", language.RouteValues, htmlAttributes);
    return link;
}
```

How LangageUrl works

```
public static Language LanguageUrl(this HtmlHelper helper, string cultureName, string languageRouteName = "lang", bool strictSelected = false)
{
    cultureName = cultureName.ToLower();
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    var queryString = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
    foreach (string key in queryString)
    {
        if (queryString[key] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            if (routeValues.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                routeValues[key] = queryString[key];
            }
            else
            {
                routeValues.Add(key, queryString[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    var actionName = routeValues["action"].ToString();
    var controllerName = routeValues["controller"].ToString();
    routeValues[languageRouteName] = cultureName;
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection);
    var url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("LocalizedDefault", routeValues);
    var current_lang_name = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLower();
    var isSelected = strictSelected ? current_lang_name == cultureName : current_lang_name.StartsWith(cultureName);
    return new Language()
    {
        Url = url,
        ActionName = actionName,
        ControllerName = controllerName,
        RouteValues = routeValues,
        IsSelected = isSelected
    };
}
```

I'm asking your help to understand why the URL is changed when I add html attributes.

I tried to understand the function 'LanguageUrl' because to my mind the problem is here but my knowledge are too weak to understand it or to understand the htmlAttributes's impact on URL.

If I made some english mistakes, please tell me I will edit my question.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to explain but let me try. There is no such override of the Method `RouteLink` accepting a type `RouteValueDictionary` as the third and html attributes of type `object`. Instead, [another override of the Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd492585(v=vs.118).aspx) is assumed automatically, where third parameter is of type `object`:

```
RouteLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routeName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
```

Now the effect is that `RouteValueDictionary` is used like an anonymous object, by reflecting it's Properties. Which is what you don't want.

One possible solution will be to convert the `htmlAttributes` to  parameter, so that [a different Method override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460287(v=vs.118).aspx) is used:

```
RouteLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes)
```

To get this working, all you have to do is convert the anonymous object to `IDictionary<string, Object>` which you will do by calling:

```
HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
```

Your new `LanguageSelectorLink`Method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LanguageSelectorLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string cultureName, string selectedText, string unselectedText, object htmlAttributes, string languageRouteName = "lang", bool strictSelected = false)
{
    var language = helper.LanguageUrl(cultureName, languageRouteName, strictSelected);
    var attributeDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    var link = helper.RouteLink(language.IsSelected ? selectedText : unselectedText, "LocalizedDefault", language.RouteValues, attributeDictionary);
    return link;
}
```

voilà!

Comment: Oh I didn't notice this difference, you're right this was the problem. Thank you for your explaination and the doc's references. I got a lot to learn and you help me to do this. Thank you really !

Answer (score 1):

I think your hitting the wrong overload, try:

```
var link = helper.RouteLink(language.IsSelected ? selectedText : unselectedText,  language.RouteValues, htmlAttributes);
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed. thank you to try help me.

Comment: I can't edit my last comment but you're right, just I didn't understand how to use your answer. Thank you mxmissile !